# Global Variables in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python

I'm trying to display the calculation for each tax amount but I've tried it a few different ways and I can't seem to get the input to stick to each module without it being asked over and over again. Therefore, I'm trying to set my input to a global variable called "Amount" but even that's giving me errors.

If you guys could tell me what I should do to fix it I would really appreciate it!

And yes, I've tried Googling/using this forum's search but I didn't find anything that applies to my dilemma.

```
def main():

    Amount = float(input())

    DollarAmount()
    StateTax()
    CountyTax()
    CityTax()
    return




def DollarAmount():

    print ("Please enter the purchase amount. You will be rewarded with the     beauty of knowledge.")
    return



def StateTax():

    Total = global Amount * 0.065 
    print("Your total state tax is " + str(Total) + ".")
    return



def CountyTax():

    Total = global Amount * 0.0125
    print("Your total county tax is " + str(Total) + ".")    
    return



def CityTax():

    Total = global Amount * 0.0075
    print("Your total city tax is " + str(Total) + ".")    
    return




main()
```

Comment: You can't use `global` in an expression. It has to be on its own line: `global variable_name_goes_here`. You can't do `x = global foo * y`

Comment: Dang. Guess I'll have to think of another way to get the input into each module without asking for it more than once. Thanks Kevin!

Comment: Well, you should learn about parameters and return values.

Comment: I'll definitely start some research on that, Daniel. Thanks for the quick help guys!

Comment: The first thing many new users try to do is make variables `global` to share them  between functions.  The last thing new users should do is use global variables.  Stop what you're doing, and follow @DanielRoseman's advice. Hint:  Pass the amount variable into each function as a parameter.